# How can I release projects on github effectively on android

Tags: android, github, publishing

I usually develop apps on android for many reasons.

And I *recently (at the asking time)* came across a framework called github and I was fascinated.

So I decided to share my projects on github, and created many repositories for them.

**However** there was a problem:

It was:

> It's hard to upload a whole project on github with normal **browsers!**

At first I created every directory trees manually and copy&pasted the contents.

Then I noticed *drag and drop feature*, which I could **not** utilize with android  browsers.

So my question is:

> How can I share my projects on github effectively on android?

Comment: I don’t believe this to be git related. Maybe remove the tag?

Comment: How can I improve this post?

Comment: Is it off topic?

Comment: For the git tag I thought yes, but it has been removed.

Comment: @evolutionxbox Yeah, I improved my knowledge about git from then and now agree with you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This feature isn't really meant to be used on a mobile device. When you are developing an app, you can use Android Studio on your development computer to commit files to a local repo and push the current branch to GitHub. As another answer states, you should read *Pro Git* to learn more about the basics of version control with Git. Focus on the first three chapters which contain almost everything you need to use Git as a programmer.

Comment: Thank you again, but I only develop apps on android with AIDE because I am not allowed to code on pc (I didn't entered college yet...)

Comment: @KYHSGeekCode Is that a restriction from your parents?

Answer (score 3):

GitHub is a hosting service for Git repositories. So you need to first learn the basics of how Git works. [Pro Git](https://git-scm.com/book) should get you started; more information available at the [Documentation page](https://git-scm.com/doc).

Comment: Thanks for your nice reference but by now I want to know how to upload a folder to www.github.com.

Answer (score 1):

I could upload folders with an application **MGit** , not chrome. So my demand has been solved.